# ¿Cómo evitar que se repita la impresión del document.write en la segunda condicional?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una especie de diccionario con dos arrays. En la segunda condicional al no estar la palabra en vez de poner una sola vez el `document.write` que no conoce la palabra, la repite tantas veces como como indice tiene el array. ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repita esa impresión?

Deseo que aparezca solo una sola vez.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA- 
    Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
        var español = ['palabra', 'sueco', 'español']
        var sueco = ['ord', 'svanska', 'spanska']
        var pala = prompt('dame la palabra')
        var encontro = false

        for (i = 0; i < español.length; i++) {
            if (pala == español[i]) {
                encontro = true
                document.write('En sueco es' + ' ' + sueco[i])
                break;
            }

            if (encontro != true) {
                document.write('No 
    conozco esa palabra')
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Super agradecido hermano.. Eso mismo era..me tenía loco el no encontrar la solución...

Answer (score 2):

Solo saca tu segundo "if" de tu "for":

```
var español = ['palabra', 'sueco', 'español']
    var sueco = ['ord', 'svanska', 'spanska']
    var pala = prompt('dame la palabra')
    var encontro = false

    for (i = 0; i < español.length; i++) {
        if (pala == español[i]) {
            encontro = true
            document.write('En sueco es' + ' ' + sueco[i])
            break;
        }
    }

        if (encontro != true) {
            document.write('No 
conozco esa palabra')
        }
```